# GLSL geometry shader requires glProgramParameteriEXT regardless of layout

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I created a basic quad drawing shader using a single point and a geometry shader.

I've read many posts and articles suggesting that I would not need to use `glProgramParameteriEXT` and could use the `layout` keyword so long as I was using a shader `#version 150` or higher.  Some suggested `#version 400` or `#version 420`.  My computer will not support `#version 420` or higher.

If I use only `layout` and `#version 150` or higher, nothing draws.  If I remove `layout` (or even keep it; it does not seem to care because it will compile) and use `glProgramParameteriEXT`, it renders.

In code, this does nothing:

```
layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=4) out;
```

This is the only code that works:

```
glProgramParameteriEXT( id, GL_GEOMETRY_INPUT_TYPE_EXT, GL_POINTS );
glProgramParameteriEXT( id, GL_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_TYPE_EXT, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP );
glProgramParameteriEXT( id, GL_GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT_EXT, 4 );
```

The alternative is to create a parser that creates the parameters via shader source.

Source for quad rendering via geometry shader:

```
#version 330

#ifdef VERTEX_SHADER

in vec4 aTexture0;
in vec4 aColor;
in mat4 aMatrix;

out vec4 gvTex0;
out vec4 gvColor;
out mat4 gvMatrix;

void main()
{
    // Texture color
    gvTex0 = aTexture0;

    // Vertex color
    gvColor = aColor;

    // Matrix
    gvMatrix = aMatrix;
}

#endif
#ifdef GEOMETRY_SHADER

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=4) out;

in vec4 gvTex0[1];
in vec4 gvColor[1];
in mat4 gvMatrix[1];

out vec2 vTex0;
out vec4 vColor;

void main()
{
    vColor = gvColor[0];

    // Top right.
    //
    gl_Position = gvMatrix[0] * vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
    vTex0 = vec2(gvTex0[0].z, gvTex0[0].y);
    EmitVertex();

    // Top left.
    //
    gl_Position = gvMatrix[0] * vec4(-1, 1, 0, 1);
    vTex0 = vec2(gvTex0[0].x, gvTex0[0].y);
    EmitVertex();

    // Bottom right.
    //
    gl_Position = gvMatrix[0] * vec4(1, -1, 0, 1);
    vTex0 = vec2(gvTex0[0].z, gvTex0[0].w);
    EmitVertex();

    // Bottom left.
    //
    gl_Position = gvMatrix[0] * vec4(-1, -1, 0, 1);
    vTex0 = vec2(gvTex0[0].x, gvTex0[0].w);
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}

#endif
#ifdef FRAGMENT_SHADER

uniform sampler2D tex0;

in vec2 vTex0;
in vec4 vColor;

out vec4 vFragColor;

void main()
{
    vFragColor = clamp(texture2D(tex0, vTex0) * vColor, 0.0, 1.0);
}

#endif
```

I am looking for suggestions as to why something like this might happen.

Comment: What version of GL are you working with? Unless you told your GLSL compiler to use the EXT form of geometry shaders, then the layout qualifiers are perfectly valid in GLSL 1.50. If you could post your full shader, that would help.

Comment: I am using OpenGL Version 4.1.0.  I am unsure how to tell my compiler to use the EXT form of geometry shaders.  It would definitely help to know how to force it to use the EXT using C++, so I can remove that portion.  I am editing my post to include the shader source as requested.

Comment: If you were using the EXT extension instead of core Geometry Shaders, there would be a line in your shader: `#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable`. (That is really only necessary in GLSL 1.40, because GS became core in 1.50) One thing that strikes me as unusual is that you are giving `gvTex0`, etc. an explicit size. You do not have to do this, `layout (points) in;` tells the GLSL compiler the size of the GS inputs (1 in this case), so you can declare it `in vec4 gvTex0[];` instead. This can be helpful when refactoring shaders.

Comment: It was originally using `gvTex0[]`, but I changed it to `gvTex0[1]` instead because this shader will not be changing. I just changed it back to `gvTex0[]`, and still no rendering.

Comment: The other thing is, you need to write all of the per-vertex outputs for every vertex you emit to have a proper GS. This is because after you call `EmitVertex (...)` every GS output becomes undefined. Unfortunately, you are only writing `vColor` one time.

Comment: Using `vColor` once works when using EXT, so it did not invalidate the variable after emitting. I tried setting `vColor` before every emit, but the results are the same.